# Flutter how to paint custom gradients

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, gradient, custom-painting

I recently experienced a problem when I was trying to create following AppBar with gradient.

[image: Expected color gradient]

When I tried to replicate this design in flutter with the colors 
rose = Color(0xFFec15ee), 
purple = Color(0xFF8561f5) and 
blue = Color(0xFF1eaefc) and set the alignment property accordingly it somehow gave me not the expected result

```
BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          AppColors.roseGradientColor,
          AppColors.purpleInAppGradientColor,
          AppColors.blueInAppGradientColor
        ],
        stops: [
          0.0,
          0.05,
          1.0
        ],
        begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        end: Alignment.topRight
      ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),bottomRight: Radius.circular(25))
    )
```

[image: d]

Just imagine the opacity wouldnt be there. As you can see I only want the rose to be aligned at the bottomLeft and not to expand up to topLeft as shown in the example.

My question how can I do that. There must a way to do that within CustomPainter yet I haven't found the right way.

Comment: insetead of `Alignment.topRight` use `Alignment` that is far above `top` - see `Alignment(double, double)` constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pskinks comment was right and I totally overlooked this option.
Using the Alignment(x,y) was the key here.

Here is the solution for my above problem.

```
BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          AppColors.roseGradientColor,
          AppColors.purpleInAppGradientColor,
          AppColors.blueInAppGradientColor
        ],
        begin: Alignment(-0.7,12),
        end: Alignment(1,-2),
      ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),bottomRight: Radius.circular(25))
    )
```

Comment: ok, but why `-0.7` in `begin` alignment? why not `-1`? `-1` is for 'left"

Comment: I gotta be honest, I tested the design with -1, -5, -10, -0.2, -0.5 and so on and I found -0.7 to be the closest at the design I want. This value was 100% found through trial and error ;)

Comment: the most important is that final result looks ok ;-)